# Python Twisted -- how to control buffered/unbuffered input in Telnet or SSH?

Tags: python, ssh, twisted, telnet

I want to write a Python Twisted server that serves text to its clients, and I want the clients to be able to write text back to manipulate the server. I will use Telnet, and the clients will use Putty or some similar terminal...I would also be open to using SSH if it is easier to do this.

My question is, how do I configure the server so that the client can send raw, unbuffered bytes (I don't want the user to have to press enter after a command)? Also, is there a way to change the configuration mid-session so that I can change back and forth to and from buffered/unbuffered bytes?

I think it is Telnet option 34 "Linemode" --- http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1700/10.htm

I just don't know how to set up Twisted to use that...

Any help setting this up for Telnet or SSH is appreciated!!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`twisted.conch.telnet.TelnetBootstrapProtocol` is a good example of how to do some option negotiation.  It also happens to perform some `LINEMODE` negotiation.  Take a look at [the implementation](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/conch/telnet.py#L878) for details, but here's a snippet that shows the server asking the client to enable linemode, naws, and sga:

```
for opt in (LINEMODE, NAWS, SGA):
    self.transport.do(opt).addErrback(log.err)
```

A real server might want to do more error handling than `log.err` if the negotiation fails, since the client will be left in a state that is presumably not ideal for use with the server.

Also take a look at some of the [funky terminal demos](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/conch/examples/) that come with Twisted.  These do lots of character-at-a-time processing.